# How do I check if I have admin access to a remote system?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

With PowerShell, how am I able to check if I have access to a remote system (example `\\SYSTEM0123\c$\`)?

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: Umm... your subject contradicts your question text. Do you want to check if you have access to a remote system (what kind of access?), or do you want to check if you have admin access on the local system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `try` it:

```
try {
    Get-Item -Path \\SYSTEM0123\c$ -ErrorAction Stop
    # if you have access these statements will run
} catch {
    # Don't have access
}
```